# Eclipse: tooltip quickfix suggestions are not displaying correctly in Ubuntu

Tags: unity, eclipse

I am new to Eclipse in Ubuntu, at first Eclipse tooltip shows only black, then I installed gnome-color-chooser and change the tooltip background and foreground color as displayable, but after the quick fix links are only 2 or 3 words displaying.

As shown

[image]

the import statements and change to statements and other statements are not displaying correctly.

Help me to solve this issue.

Comment: According to me, this bug is not related to Gnome or Unity. Some of my imports (usually the ones coming from jars) show the class name, but suggestions coming from Java source files seems being often displayed as just "Import". This is annoying because you have to blindly click on it and hope it was the good one... I guess it's an Eclipse 4.x bug.

Comment: I'm having this problem also.  I'm finding it nearly impossible to form my question as a google search, but I did manage to find this.

Is there a bug open with eclipse somewhere? any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=393602

There is a workaround:
I changed the font in Eclipse

Go to preferences-->general-->appearance-->Colors and Fonts

Change: 
'Dialog Font' and 'Javadoc display font'

To monospace 10 (Default is Ubuntu 11)

That fixed this for me.

Example image:

[image]